# SQL - DATA AGGREGATION

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, where-clause

```
SELECT
    t1.lastname,
    SUM(t3.quantity * t3.unit_price) Total_sales
FROM employees t1
INNER JOIN orders t2 ON t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id
INNER JOIN order_details t3 ON t3.order_id = t2.order_id
GROUP BY t1.lastname
ORDER BY 1
```

The question is: 
Which employee served orders at what value in the period 2014-2016?
The data must be sorted by last name and year. How can I add year 2014 to year 2016.

I tried:

```
WHERE t2.order_date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
```

But it is not showing any result.

Thank you

Comment: Plaese tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: oracle database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `where` clause. In Oracle, you can declare literal dates with the standard `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'` syntax, so:

```
select e.lastname, sum(od.quantity * od.unit_price) total_sales
from employees e
inner join orders o         on o.employee_id = e.employee_id
inner join order_details od on od.order_id = o.order_id
where o.order_date >= date '2014-01-01' and o.order_date < date '2017-01-01'
group by e.employee_id, e.lastname
order by 1
```

Other changes to your query:

- I added `employee_id` to the `group by` clause; this the case when two employees have the same `lastname` (in which case your original query would count their sales together)
- using half-open intervals to filter date makes it simpler to handle the upper boundary - and it is more accurate in general (if your dates had a time part, your expression would actually filter out the last day)
- *meaningful* table aliases make the query much easier to read and write

If you want the results grouped by employee *and* year, then you need to add another column to the `select` and `group by` clauses:

```
select 
    e.lastname, 
    extract(year from o.order_date) year_sales,
    sum(od.quantity * od.unit_price) total_sales
from employees e
inner join orders o         on o.employee_id = e.employee_id
inner join order_details od on od.order_id = o.order_id
where o.order_date >= date '2014-01-01' and o.order_date < date '2017-01-01'
group by e.employee_id, e.lastname, extract(year from o.order_date)
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Even though I'm using a WHERE clause I get the following result:Buchanan 75567.75
Callahan 130780.93
Davolio 199959.71
Dodsworth 82586
Fuller 176868.76
King 134120.29
Leverling 209896.62
Peacock 245202.05
Suyama 75864.9       Employee Total Sales

Comment: @DianaNacheva: it seems like you want the results grouped by employee *and year*. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should be a *fairly* RDBMS neutral query

```
    SELECT
        t1.lastname
    ,   SUM(t3.quantity * t3.unit_price) Total_sales
    ,   YEAR(t2.order_date) AS Year
    FROM employees t1
    INNER JOIN orders t2 ON t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id
    INNER JOIN order_details t3 ON t3.order_id = t2.order_id
    WHERE t2.order_date>= '2014-01-01' AND t2.order_date<='2016-12-31'
    GROUP BY t1.lastname, YEAR(t2.order_date)
    ORDER BY t1.lastname asc, YEAR(t2.order_date) ASC
```

Comment: well neutral in meaning SQL Server, MySql, and Oracle. In postgres its date_part

Comment: It doesn't work properly - it's written invalid identifier